# Issue inserting a BSON document into MongoDB Atlas using Rust

Tags: mongodb, rust, bson

```rs
let db = super::setup().await.unwrap();

let users_collection = db.collection::<Document>("users");

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: i32,
}

let person = Person {
    name: "Alice".to_string(),
    age: 25,
};

let bson_doc = to_bson(&person).unwrap();

// Insert the BSON document into the MongoDB collection
users_collection.insert_one(bson_doc, None).await.unwrap();

println!("{}", bson_doc);

let insert_result = users_collection.insert_one(bson_doc, None).await.unwrap(); //WILL FAIL
println!("New document ID: {}", insert_result.inserted_id);
```

Trying to insert a struct into Atlas by serializing it into a BSON document.

The issue that I'm getting with above code is the `insert_one` method has a trait bound where the BSON document being inserted must implement the Borrow trait.

The trait bound `bson::Bson: std::borrow::Borrow<bson::Document>` is not satisfied
the trait `std::borrow::Borrow<bson::Document>` is not implemented for `bson::Bson`

What doesn't really make sense is that does MongoDB expect its users to do this or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 1):

Issue was trying to turn the struct into a BSON when it should have been serialized into a Document.

Fix: replace the `to_bson` method with `to_document`.